# CSS For responsive sidebar and main content?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I found what im looking for ALMOST, (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqxQVN).

But the only problem is i need the container to have height of auto and the sidebar to have a height of 100%. When i do that the sidebar disappears.

```
    #container { height:500px; width:100% }
.sidebar { background:red; float:right; height:100%; width:20% }
.content { background:green; height: 100px; width:80%; float:left; margin-top: 20px;}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) { 
  .sidebar { clear:both; width:100% }
  .content { width:100%; }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: so in mobile or tab view you can see side bar? right?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the universal selector (*) to remove padding and margin, therefore the sidebar will be 100% of height.

For what concerns the green container, by simply removing the height from 100px to "auto" it will automatically fill the content.

[Link to codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGMRgM)

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#container { height:500px; width:100% }
.sidebar { background:red; float:right; height:100%; width:20% }
.content { background:green; height: auto; width:80%; float:left; margin-top: 20px}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) { 
 .sidebar { clear:both; width:100% }
.content { width:100%; }
}
```

This design isn't perfect as you might find some text going under the sidebar, but should be a good start.

Regards,
-Gallo

Comment: if you use height:auto on the #container, the .sidebar disappears because it has no content.
if you write on it it will increase to as much as you need it.

You can have the sidebar to be as high as you want but you'll have to hard code the size.

Comment: how do i make the sidebar 100%

Answer (score 0):

give the height to sidebar as .sidebar{height:500px;} not to container

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#container { height:auto; width:100% }
.sidebar { background:red; float:right; height:500px; width:20% }
.content { background:green; height: 100px; width:80%; float:left; margin-top: 20px;}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) { 
  .sidebar { clear:both; width:100% }
  .content { width:100%; }
}
```